# I am trying to add table in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
$(document.ready(function() {
  var laterbox = document.getElementById('laterbox');
  var tabl = document.createElement('table');
  var trh = document.createElement('tr');
  var trd = document.createElement('tr');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('book_id');
  var tr1 = document.createElement('th');
  tr1.appendChild(txt);
  trh.appendChild(tr1);
  tabl.appendChild(trh);
  tabl.appendChild(trd);
  laterbox.appendChild(tabl);
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="laterbox">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>aa</th>
      <th>bb</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

But the second table does't display, I don't know why. I tried many times but could not find the error. You can see the output here: https://codepen.io/sandesh_bafna8/pen/BwQZGv

Comment: Others have already answered the question so I'm just leaving some general advice for debugging JS here. Inspect the output of your browsers console when running your script, errors like this get flagged immediately. Also use more descriptive variable names - it might work on a small script like this, but figuring out what `tabl1`, `tr1` and stuff like that do in a bigger codebase is a real pain and leads to more time spent figuring it out than the time it would take to type `tableToInsert` or `tableRow`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var laterbox = document.getElementById('laterbox');
  var tabl = document.createElement('table');
  var trh = document.createElement('tr');
  var trd = document.createElement('tr');
  var txt = document.createTextNode('book_id');
  var tr1 = document.createElement('th');
  tr1.appendChild(txt);
  trh.appendChild(tr1);
  tabl.appendChild(trh);
  tabl.appendChild(trd);
  laterbox.appendChild(tabl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="laterbox">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>aa</th>
      <th>bb</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

`$(document.ready(function() {` => `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 2):

You don't have `)` in your `document` and extra `)` at the end. Remove it and it will work..

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var laterbox=document.getElementById('laterbox');
        var tabl=document.createElement('table');
        var trh=document.createElement('tr');
    var trd=document.createElement('tr');
   var txt=document.createTextNode('book_id');
   var tr1=document.createElement('th');
 tr1.appendChild(txt);
 trh.appendChild(tr1);
  tabl.appendChild(trh);
  tabl.appendChild(trd);
  laterbox.appendChild(tabl);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="laterbox">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>aa</th>
         <th>bb</th>
        </tr>
       <tr>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

**Tip:** If your code is not working try to look at the console if there is an error.. Missing or extra bracket and parenthesis will be displayed as an error in there..

Comment: ya syntax was correct i missed it, one more error was i missed jquery link

Comment: @sandeshbafna If this solve your problem just mark it as the answer. So that this question would be closed and of course +rep for both of us..

Answer (score 1):

You have some typo errors:

1. `$(document.ready(function() {` should be `$(document).ready(function() {`
2. Closing `}));` should be `});`

Here is the corrected code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var laterbox=document.getElementById('laterbox');
  var tabl=document.createElement('table');
  var trh=document.createElement('tr');
  var trd=document.createElement('tr');
  var txt=document.createTextNode('book_id');
  var tr1=document.createElement('th');
  
  tr1.appendChild(txt);
  trh.appendChild(tr1);
  tabl.appendChild(trh);
  tabl.appendChild(trd);
  laterbox.appendChild(tabl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="laterbox">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <th>aa</th>
         <th>bb</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
       </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```